# FDQuery append gives error "no such table"

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firedac

In Delphi 10.1 I made a small program to learn about FireDAC and SQlite.

I have `FDConnection`, `FDQuery` (with `SQL= SELECT * FROM Sætning`) and `DataSource + DBGrid`.
The `DBGrid` shows the (empty) table `Sætning`. I want to put data into my table from a listbox containg a CSV.

This is my code: (`fdwSætning` = an `FDQuery`)

```
procedure TMainForm.bCSV_SQLite_SætningClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  loop : integer;
  nr, lang, tekst : string;
begin
  { Read CSV file into Listbox }
  Listbox1.Items.LoadFromFile('GMS_Saetninger.txt');
  { Put the values from the CSV into the fields in each record }
  for loop:= 0 to Listbox1.Items.Count-1 do begin
    fdqSætning.Edit;
    nr:= copy(Listbox1.Items[loop],1,4);
    lang:= copy(Listbox1.Items[loop],5,2);
    tekst:= copy(Listbox1.Items[loop],8, length(Listbox1.Items[loop]));
    fdqSætning.Append;
    fdqSætning.FieldByName('SAETNING_ID').AsString:= nr;
    fdqSætning.FieldByName('LANGUAGE').AsString:= lang;
    fdqSætning.FieldByName('SENTENCE').AsString:= tekst;
    fdqSætning.Post;
  end;
end;
```

When I run this code I get the error message

```
[FireDAC][phys][SQLite]ERROR:no such table: Sætning
```

Comment: Not that I would like to discourage you, but I would suggest you to use ASCII names for tables. I bet there is a setting for it, I can search for, but still...

Comment: Indeed, my instinct is that special character you have in the table name. Internally, something probably interprets it as `S?tning`.

Comment: Thank you Victoria and Jerry!
You were right. I changed the table name from Sætning to Saetning and now there is no "no such table" error.
Instead I got me a "[FireDAC][phys][SQLite]ERROR: database is locked" - this is for sure a time-consuming hobby... :-)

Comment: I bet you just forgot to disconnect the connection at design time (`Connected` property of your connection object). But my initial comment was just a suggestion. I'm not saying it's impossible. FireDAC should fully support Unicode table names in Unicode Delphi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should not happen. Since Delphi 2009, [**FireDAC fully supports Unicode metadata values**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Unicode_Support_(FireDAC)#Metadata_Values), so as [**does SQLite DBMS**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_SQLite_with_FireDAC#Working_with_Unicode_and_SQLite_Databases). Possible explanation for what you describe is that you've created your table in some external tool (which cannot save Unicode metadata).

So even when I would highly suggest using only ASCII chars for database object names, you can still do something like this with FireDAC since Delphi 2009:

```
FDConnection.Params.Add('DriverID=SQLite');
FDConnection.Params.Add('Database=C:\MyDatabase.db');

FDQuery.SQL.Text := 'CREATE TABLE ṀÿṪäḅḷë (MɏFɨɇłđ INTEGER)';
FDQuery.ExecSQL;
FDQuery.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO ṀÿṪäḅḷë (MɏFɨɇłđ) VALUES (1234)';
FDQuery.ExecSQL;
FDQuery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT MɏFɨɇłđ FROM ṀÿṪäḅḷë';
FDQuery.Open;
Assert(FDQuery.FieldByName('MɏFɨɇłđ').AsInteger = 1234);
```

Comment: Allthough I changed to ANSI and renamed my tables (which solved the problem), I think that the "no such table" problem was generated - as you say - because of a unicode problem. In my FDConnection the string was not set to Unicode (by default you have to choose).

Comment: No, by default, FireDAC picks the best for you.

Comment: The othe problem ("database locked") was correctly caused by having my FDConnection still active in the Delphi IDE. - Well, when you are in the middle of "the steep learning curve" there is too many unknown factors.... Thanks for the fine answers!!!

Comment: You're very welcome! Well, what would I appreciate now is if you could do a quick test with a fresh project composed from a connection (named `FDConnection`) and query object (named `FDQuery`) with default settings and run the code I've posted to verify that Unicode works for you in Delphi 10.1. Of course naming table and field like I did is horrible, but I would like a proof. If that works, you may consider [accept this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/367405), when it raises an `EAssertionFailed` exception, then there's something wrong with Unicode.